# Sobre tag meta name="author" content="">

Tags: html, html5

Uma duvida que sempre tenho, essa Meta tag é para o nome do dono da empresa ou quem fez o template?

```
meta name="author" content="">
```

Answer (score 1):

A meta tag *author* serve como uma espécie de assinatura eletrônica de quem desenvolveu a página. Se foi criada por um desenvolvedor autônomo, pode-se colocar o nome do desenvolvedor; se o desenvolvedor trabalha para a empresa dona da página, pode-se colocar, além do nome do desenvolvedor, o nome da empresa também, tanto faz. Não existe uma norma pra isso.

Nome do desenvolvedor:

```
<meta name="author" content="João">
```

Ou nome da empresa:

```
<meta name="author" content="Empresa X">
```

Ou ambos:

```
<meta name="author" content="João - Empresa X">
```

Comment: Ótimo, obrigado e desculpa a demora no retorno

Comment: Tranquilo amigão. Sucesso!

Answer (score 0):

Eu te indicaria usa a *meta tag* `copyright` caso vc quera declarar quem é o proprietário dos direitos autorais do template.

```
<meta name="copyright" content="© 2018 Wesley Vicente" />
```

Vc também pode usar as *tags* [Dublin Core Metadata](http://dublincore.org/) para declarar isso.

```
<meta name="DC.rights" content="https://Wesley-Vicent.com/termos-de-uso.html">
```

ou

```
<meta name="dcterms:rightsHolder" content="Wesley Vicent">
```

https://terms.tdwg.org/wiki/dcterms:rightsHolder 
http://dublincore.org/documents/dcmi-terms/#terms-rightsHolder

Assim vc deixa a autoria do conteúdo da página para quem realmente for usar o template, porém reserva os direitos autorais da criação do template para vc. Eu vejo `author` como "quem escreve" e não como "proprietário dos direitos". A documentação não é muito clara sobre esse assunto... e vai da sua interpretação e ética também dependendo do caso...

---

O interessante é que boa parte das meta tags são ignoradas pelos mecanismos de busca e pelo próprio browser. Aqui tem uma lista completa, e inclusive tem uma tag `web_author` para indicar quem desenvolveu o site https://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/MetaExtensions

Faça um teste vc mesmo, pege o código abaixo com a meta tag customizada `<meta name="desenvolvedor" content=" seu nome aqui">` e teste no validador de código da W3C que vc vai ver que não vai apresentar erros. https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <!-- tag meta customizasda -->
    <meta name="desenvolvedor" content=" seu nome aqui">
    
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```